# What model to use to predict multiple binary time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, prediction, binary-data

[image]

I have dataset similar to above one. It contains ~ 1 lakh observations and and ~ 30 columns (those are my columns).

I want to predict whether a particular individual is likely to watch television in a given time slot or not, for upcoming days(day5, day6, day7 in example above).
I looked for time series forecasting, but doubt that it would  be a good fit this case, as my data is binary entries and I am dealing with multiple individuals, therefore I will have to forecast for each individual at a time.

I thought of using random forest - wherein I thought of  considering column -(Day4) as a target variable and Day1, Day2, Day3 would be independent variables.  Train model on first three columns keeping fourth column values as my dependent variable.
Later, predict for Day5 and so on for other Days ( Days6, Days7 ...)

Which algorithm should I use in such case?

Comment: Do you assume that the patterns between the individual would be somehow correlated? If not, then using independent models per individual would make sense.

Comment: I assume patterns would be correlated .                                                                    There are around 100000 individuals in actual dataset for which building independent model would not be feasible.                                                       I thought of running random forest  - Day 1 to Day 3 would be independent variable. Day 4 data as target variable. Train the model using this data. And then using the trained model to predict for day 5 considering day 2 to day 4 data as independent unseen data. which will give prediction for the Day 5.

Comment: But in this case, If we need to predict for next 10 days then we have to iterate this process( that means iterate this model ) and that would take lot of computation.